# Правильная выборка по COUNT

Tags: php, mysqli

Пытаюсь вывести ежедневные приёмы врачей из таблицы priem. Выборка должна быть по ежедневной дате, т.е. сколько пациентов принимал каждый врач каждый день:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT prdate, fio, doctor_uid, COUNT(*) 
    FROM priem WHERE doctor_uid=$uidforfaq GROUP BY prdate");
```

Здесь `prdate` - столбец с датой приёма, `fio` - ФИО пациента, `doctor_uid` - уникальный идентификатор каждого врача. исходя из вышеуказанного запроса как вывести количество приёма в цифрах. Т.е. например 2017-06-14 - 4 приёма, 2017-06-13 - 2 приёма.

Comment: Группируйте по `prdate, fio, doctor_uid`, а не только по дате.

Comment: Так и сделал , но теперь каждую дату отображает столько же сколько было приёмов в этот день.А хотелось бы дату один раз а рядом цифра  количество приёмов за этот день. И показывать ФИО пациентов внутри это даты

Comment: Не правильно понял ваше фио, прочиталось не как пациента, а как врача :) Если бы не нужны были фио пациентов, то можно было группировку по дате и номеру врача сделать, а так - пусть кто-нибудь другой придумает хитрый запрос ;)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: А у вас там дата или дата с временем. если второе, то при группировке время надо отбросить (с помощью функции `date()`). А так группировка по `prdate, doctor_uid` должна давать верный результат. А fio разве что списком с помощью group_concat как в комментарии выше

Comment: Спасибо всем за идеи и советы. Решил проблему слегка по другому. Изменил запрос. Что то по этому запросу что указал выше никак не получается. Создал ещё одну таблицу именно для формы 37 (форма 37-стоматологическая форма где есть информация о приёмах каждого врача.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выборка должна быть по ежедневной дате, то дату следует указать в условиях выборки. Только тогда выборка будет работать как вы хотите.

```
SELECT prdate, fio, doctor_uid, COUNT(*) FROM priem
  WHERE doctor_uid=1 AND prdate = "2017-07-20" 
  GROUP BY doctor_uid
```

Соответственно на каждую дату у вас будет один SQL запрос. Сомнительно что у вас миллиард посещений и миллион врачей, но если окажется что запрос выполняется медленно и добавление индексов не помогает, то результаты такого запроса удобно кешировать: данные на позавчера вряд ли когда-нибудь изменятся.

Если всё же каким-то способом добьётесь получения всего набора данных одним SQL запросом, то вы не сможете его положить в кеш: вы должны будете выполнять его каждый раз всегда. Подумайте, может быть вам это не выгодно.

Comment: sanmai, спасибо за ответ и за помощь !